# Can't install Openjdk 1.6 in ubuntu

Tags: apt

Accidentally I removed Openjdk from Ubuntu. Now it is not possible to install it again.It gives error that:

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main tzdata all 2014c-0ubuntu0.12.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

I used to try `sudo apt-get update` also.

Finally it gives:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  openjdk-6-jre-lib ca-certificates-java tzdata tzdata-java openjdk-6-jre-headless libgif4 openjdk-6-jre libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libxt-dev ttf-dejavu-extra icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx-common icedtea-netx openjdk-6-jdk
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main tzdata all 2014c-0ubuntu0.12.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main tzdata-java all 2014c-0ubuntu0.12.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libxt-dev amd64 1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1 [490 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main openjdk-6-jdk amd64 6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 [16.0 MB]
Fetched 16.5 MB in 59s (278 kB/s)                                                                                                                      
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2014c-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata-java_2014c-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try installing again. Also, you'll likely have updates to other packages available.

Comment: I tried that also.But not working..

Comment: Change your server mirror with [this article](http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/configure/) before update.

Comment: Did you mean ubuntu software centre

Comment: sorry.I could not find any article their..

Comment: http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/configure/

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu Software Center: [OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openjdk-6-jre/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need openjdk? it's slow and not fully implemented. Use java instead.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Since June of 2017, the traditional way to install the Java 6,  [does not work](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html). Note that [Java 1.6 is not supported anymore](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-downloads-1637591.html) by Oracle neither.

---

**The traditional way to install Java**

The [typical method to install Java](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/oracle-sun-java-6-installer-available.html) is adding the webup8 repository and using `apt-get` to install the software.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer     # this does not work
```

Currently, I think you can install [Java 8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) or [Java 9](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html).

---

**An alternative method**

You may try to download the installer from the [Java download archive](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) using a Browser. There is a `.bin` file that is [a self-extracting installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-64-self-extracting-142068.html).

For instance, if you download the `jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin`, you must run that file

```
$ jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
```